# How to hide Yii dropdownlist search field?

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm trying to make a drop-down list with just two options, Yes and No, But by default Yii adds Searchfield as the first option. How do I remove it?

```php
<?= Html::dropDownList(
    'has-experience', 
    false, 
    [false => 'No', true => 'Yes'], 
    ['style' => 'width: 64px']
) ?>
```

This is how it shows up in html

```html
<input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="select2-has-own-instrument-z6-results">
```

Comment: The code you posted should generate a select with just two options, are you sure the search field is not coming from somewhere else? I pasted your code into a Yii2 project and checked the generated html in the developer tools, `<select name="has-experience" style="width: 64px">
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>`. The search field maybe generated by something in your code before that line, or maybe you have some JS that is modifying the generated field. I tested on Yii2 2.0.38

Comment: @RaulSauco Maybe. Not sure. Any ideas of how to check it?

Comment: To see if the search field is being generated in PHP: Put some element that you can identify above the `select`, for example `<div id="my-test-div">Test</div>` and check in the browser development tools. If the search field is above the `div` is being generated by something else.

Comment: To see if the search field is being added by javascript, disable all JS in your page, also in the browser development tools, if after that the select is what you expect, then the problem is that you have a _dropdown to search field_ plugin installed? Maybe something like `select2`

Comment: @RaulSauco that ::DropDownList automatically generates those select2

Comment: [Select2](https://select2.org/) is a jQuery plugin to _add functionality_ to native selects. By default `yii\helpers\Html` just generates a native `select`, and, if I copy your code, that is what I get, no select. Which `Html` class are you using? If you are using an extension of the base helper, that could be what adds `select2` otherwise, you may have added an asset, or maybe your layout has a `<script>` tag that adds `select2` check the `js` tab on the dev tools and you should see that `select2` is being added from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Html::dropDownList('fieldName', yourselctedVale or '', ['1' => enable, '0' => disable]);

Comment: This makes it so the default option selected is yes or no, and that works well, but I wanted to get rid of the search box with is a top option of the dropdown.